# Do I earn two energy cubes if I end my 5th register on an energy space?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

The rules on page 8 say

> When you end a register on an **energy space**, if there is an energy cube there, take it. If you end the fifth register on an energy space, take an energy cube from the energy bank.

I take this to mean that you take a cube from that space if you land there after executing the fifth register, but you additionally take one from the bank, so could gain two.  Is that right?

Comment: That's how it reads to me, but it would be really nice if they had said "also take..." there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

If you end any register on a space that has an energy cube you get that cube. If you end the 5th register on an energy space you get a cube from the bank. These statuses are both checked independently.